# build html string dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I am using javascript to build html string and calling function inside it.

```
myString= "<a href='#' onClick='return openfunc(400, 350, \"" + fbAppId + 
          ",\"" + singlePageUrl + ",\"" + imageUrl  + "\" )' title='Share This on Facebook' ><span class='icon-facebook'></span></a>";
```

But when page is rendered I get below output:

```
onclick="return openfunc(400, 350, "1714185588815613,"http://mysite/Pages/default.aspx,"http://mysite/sites/id/Attachments/63/image2.PNG" )"
```

As you can see it's missing `"` after each parameter.

I get this error in the console when I click on the link.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Is there a better way to build the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didnt insert the `"`? Your missing it:

```
myString= "<a href='#' onClick='return openfunc(400, 350, \"" + fbAppId + 
      ",\"" + singlePageUrl + ",\"" + imageUrl  + "\" )' title='Share This on Facebook' ><span class='icon-facebook'></span></a>";
//     ^                       ^
//     |_________________      |_
//                       |       |
//     a \" is missing here and here
```

Comment: i still get Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: Man please use your brain for your own I wont debug your whole code, google for the error if you dont know what it means

Comment: sorry man. I was passing wrong link in the parameter and thats why it was giving that error

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add an extra escaped quote character after fbAppId and singlePageUrl

```
myString= "<a href='#' onClick='return openfunc(400, 350, \"" + fbAppId + 
      "\",\"" + singlePageUrl + "\",\"" + imageUrl  + "\" )' title='Share This     on Facebook' ><span class='icon-facebook'></span></a>";
```

Comment: i still get Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Answer (score 1):

You might consider coding this a different way so that you're not relying on inline JavaScript. In this example I've used 1) an `id` on the anchor, 2) an array and `join` to easily build the string (no need to worry about escaping quotes), 3) data attributes, and 4) a non-inline function that takes in information from the data attributes and returns the `openfunc` function.

```
var fbAppId = '1714185588815613';
var singlePageUrl = 'http://mysite/Pages/default.aspx';
var imageUrl = 'http://mysite/sites/id/Attachments/63/image2.PNG'

var myString = [
    '<a id="clicker" title="Share This on Facebook" ',
    'data-fbappid="',
    fbAppId,
    '" data-singlepageurl="',
    singlePageUrl,
    '" data-imageurl="',
    imageUrl,
    '"',
    '>Click me<span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>'
].join('');
```

Which gives you the following string:

```
<a id="clicker" title="Share This on Facebook" data-fbappid="1714185588815613" data-singlepageurl="http://mysite/Pages/default.aspx" data-imageurl="http://mysite/sites/id/Attachments/63/image2.PNG">Click me<span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
```

Now assign the click event to our element:

```
var anchor = document.querySelector('#clicker').onclick = clicker;
```

Which calls `clicker`. This prevents the anchor from going anywhere and grabs the relevant information from the data attributes:

```
function clicker(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var fbAppId = this.getAttribute('data-fbappid')
    var singlePageUrl = this.getAttribute('data-singlepageurl')
    var imageUrl = this.getAttribute('data-imageurl')
    return openfunc(400, 350, fbAppId, singlePageUrl, imageUrl);
}
```

[A small DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/08agprjz/12/) of how this all fits together.